# How to achieve a function similar to the deconstruction assignment?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to achieve a function similar to the deconstruction assignment?

```
const res = foo([1, [2,3], [4,5,[6,[7,8]]]], '[a, [b, c], [d, [e, [f]]]]')
// res = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 6, f: 7}
```

foo ? Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting question but I'm afraid there's no magical way: you'll have to parse the second argument (I'd personally use a recursive parsing and read both structures at the same time). We could do it but I'm not sure doing this job for you is really what SO is for.

Comment: I just want to understand why this question is voted down , it is clear and interesting one

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher Probably because "This question does not show any research effort [...]".

Comment: hi @Denys Séguret ,Can you give me a case code? Thank you.

Comment: You could use the babeljs transpiler [https://babeljs.io/repl/](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgNoEMA0i2ARoRALqHYAmVKVw5T5AlIgN4BQiinAvkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on

- a JSON parsing (with a trick) to build a structure from the second argument
- a recursive parallel descent in both arrays, as hinted in my comment

```js
function foo(arr, desc){
  var map = {};
  (function dive(arr, struct){
 struct.forEach((v, i) => {
  if (arr[i] === undefined) return;
  if (Array.isArray(v)) {
   dive(arr[i], v);
  } else {
   map[v] = arr[i];
  }
 });
  })(arr, JSON.parse(desc.replace(/\w+/g, '"$&"')));
  return map;
}

const res = foo([1, [2,3], [4, [6,[7,8]]]], '[a, [b, c], [d, [e, [f]]]]')
//                            ^ I removed not matching data here

console.log(res);
```

Note that it assumes the data matches the structure. You'd better add error handling in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

My solution defers from the OP's original request, as it accepts an array of keys, and not string. I think that it reflects the "similar to the deconstruction assignment" request better than a string.

This is a recursive solution that accepts an array of values, and an array of keys with the same shape, and uses [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate the keys, and extract the matching values.

If you want to skip a value, use `null` as the key.

**Note:** You should add checks to ascertain that the shapes are similar, and throw errors/use defaults if they are different.

```js
const destructor = (values, keys) => {
  const obj = {};
  
  const iterate = (values, keys) =>
    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
      if(key === null) {
        return;
      }
      if(Array.isArray(key)) iterate(values[i], key)
      else obj[key] = values[i]
    })
    
  iterate(values, keys)
  
  return obj;
}

const res = destructor([1, [2,3], [4,5,[6,[7,8]]]], ['a', ['b', 'c'], ['d', null, ['e', ['f']]]])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: The second argument for this function is an array, not a string, the questions define a string as a second param

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher - Thanks. I know, and I'll point out in the answer that it defers from the request.

Comment: This is simply solved using JSON.parse, to convert the string to an array

Comment: Just a minor observation: `['d', 'e',` are not on same level.

Comment: @Rajesh - the original structure has a missing letter.

Comment: @scagood - it requires a bit more, and you can see it in [Denys Séguret's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48743519/5157454).

Comment: @OriDrori I dont think so. `d: 4, e: 6, f: 7` as per OP's expected output.

Comment: @Rajesh - The problem is [4, 5, [6 vs, [d, [e in the original structure. And you can't skip a value.

Comment: @OriDrori I guess Thats the whole point. Selecting values based on available keys. But lets OP decide what suits the requirement.

Comment: @Rajesh - might be. I've added a `null` as skip option.

Comment: You're of course right @OriDrori, you should do something like `JSON.parse(str.replace(/(?:"([^"]+)"|(\w+))/g, '"$1$2"'))` or possibly `JSON.parse(str.replace(/([^[,\]]+)/g, '"$1"'))`,

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of this:

```
function destructor(values, keys) {
    const output = {};
    const kReg = /(?:"([^"]+)"|'([^']+)'|(\w+))/g;
    keys = keys.replace(/\{[^{}]+\}/g, match => match.replace(kReg, '"$1$2$3":"$1$2$3"'));
    keys = keys.replace(kReg, '"$1$2$3"');

    keys = JSON.parse(keys);

    function forAll(array, func, loc) {
        loc = loc || [];

        if (typeof array === 'object') {
            const nest = Object.assign({}, array);
            for (let a in nest) {
                if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(nest, a)) {
                    nest[a] = forAll(nest[a], func, loc.concat(a));
                }
            }

            return nest;
        } else {
            return func(array, loc);
        }
    }
    function nestedGet(values, path) {
        const key = path.shift();

        return key === undefined ? values : (
            typeof values[key] === 'undefined' ? 
            undefined : nestedGet(values[key], path)
        );
    }

    forAll(keys, (elem, path) => {
        output[elem] = nestedGet(values, path)
    });

    return output;
}
```

The key difference between this version and other versions is that you can also use `{key1, key2}` esq deconstructions.

For example:

```
destructor(
     [1, [2, 3], [4, {e:5, f:6}]],
    '[a, [b, c], [d, {e,   f  }]]'
);
```

Becomes:

```
{
    'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'c':3,
    'd':4,
    'e':5,
    'f':6
}
```

Your example:

```
destructor(
     [1, [2, 3], [4, 5, [6, [7, 8]]]],
    '[a, [b, c], [d, [e, [f]]]]'
);
```

Becomes:

```
{
    'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'c':3,
    'd':4,
    'e':undefined,
    'f':undefined
}
```